# vb.net how to open mdichild in mdiparent? using ToolStrip

Tags: vb.net

This is my code, why is it when i open my first form (MdiParent) and when i open the frmCashin form (mdiChild) the child form still exceeds the parents form

```
Private Sub ToolStrip_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles ToolStrip.Click
    Dim formcashin As New frmPOSCashIn

    Dim formcashout As New frmPOSTCashout

    If CashIn.Selected Then
        formcashin.MdiParent = Me.MdiParent
        formcashin.Show()

    ElseIf Cashout.Selected Then
        formcashout.MdiParent = Me.MdiParent
        formcashout.Show()
    End If
End Sub
```

just like this in the picture (i use dual monitor), I am new in .net technology,
I can drag the child form to outside the parent form

[image]

**UPDATE**

```
    If CashIn.Selected Then
        Dim formcashin As New frmPOSCashIn
        Dim formcashout As New frmPOSTCashout
        Dim mainform As New frmMain

        formcashin.MdiParent = mainform.MdiParent
        formcashin.Show()

    ElseIf Cashout.Selected Then
        Dim formcashin As New frmPOSCashIn
        Dim formcashout As New frmPOSTCashout
        Dim mainform As New frmMain

        formcashout.MdiParent = mainform.MdiParent
        formcashout.Show()
    End If
```

Comment: Debug your code! You should have done that before posting here. Look at this line of code: `formcashin.MdiParent = Me.MdiParent`. Does that make any sense? What is the value of `Me.MdiParent`? I shouldn't need to tell you to look at that.

Comment: Why are you creating both forms first when you know that you're only going to use one of them? You should be creating one form in the `If` block because that's where it gets used, and the other in the `Else` block because that's where it gets used.

Comment: can you please show me your answer? idont really get what your saying , i download this code from google

Comment: i think i use the if condition because i have two form and two button in toolstrip

Comment: You're declaring the Forms: `Dim formcashin As New frmPOSCashIn`, before you know whether you have to show them, so that code should be inside the `If` block. What is `Me`, here? It's probably the MDI Form itself. So just, e.g., `formcashin.MdiParent = Me`.

Comment: Downloading code you don't understand and asking us to explain it to you is not how it works. You need to make an effort. If you don't know how the code works, learn. Do some reading on how MDI works and work out what that code is actually doing and whether that's what you actually want to do. For that code to have worked, the example from which you got it would have to have one major difference to what you're doing, i.e. the code would have to be in another child window, not the parent window. If you understand how MDI works then the difference that makes to the code should be obvious.

Comment: I didn't tell you not to use the `If` statement. Read what I actually wrote and do what I actually said.

Comment: I just updated the code, i already posted here, please check

Comment: Argh! Please put some thought into what you're doing. In the `If` block you are ONLY using `formcashin` so that is the only one you should be creating. Don't create `formcashout` or `mainform` because you are not using either of them. Similarly for the `Else` block, only create what you're going to use. Do you go to the supermarket and by beef and chicken, then decide which one to use and throw the other away? Of course you don't, because that would be stupid. You decide what you need first and then you get just what you need. This is no different to that so think about what you're doing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the code you posted, I assume that `frmMain` represents your main form (which is the MDI parent form) and that `frmPOSCashIn` and `frmPOSTCashOut` are two MDI child forms. And based on the screenshot, the toolstrip seems to be included in `frmMain`.

To wrap up the comments by [jmcilhinney](https://stackoverflow.com/users/584183) and [Jimi](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7444103):

- You should not explicitly create a `mainform` variable. You can just use `Me`, since you are already executing within a `frmMain` form instance.
- Since your `frmMain` instance itself is the MDI container (its `IsMdiContainer` property is set to `True`), it itself should be used as the value for the `MdiParent` property of your child forms (whose `IsMdiContainer` properties are set to `False`). (The MDI architecture allows only one level of hierarchy. You cannot nest MDI container forms as MDI children in an(other) MDI container form. So you should never use the `MdiParent` property of an MDI container form.)
- You can declare your MDI child form variables inside the If-block. And in each block, you should only declare the variable that you actually need.

Something like this:

```
Private Sub ToolStrip_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles ToolStrip.Click
    If CashIn.Selected Then
        Dim formcashin As New frmPOSCashIn
        formcashin.MdiParent = Me
        formcashin.Show()
    ElseIf Cashout.Selected Then
        Dim formcashout As New frmPOSTCashout
        formcashout.MdiParent = Me
        formcashout.Show()
    End If
End Sub
```

If you are new to this stuff, I would suggest that you first check out some tutorials/walkthroughs in the Microsoft documentation or other sources on the Internet.

Comment: thank you so much for posting your answer, i receive this error System.ArgumentException: 'Form cannot be both an MDI child and MDI parent. (Parameter 'value')'

Comment: Please check the `IsMdiContainer` property of your `frmPOSCashIn` and `frmPOSTCashOut` forms. It should be set to `False` for both those MDI child forms.